# Copy a specific column in another file

Tags: linux, text-processing

I would like to copy the second column of `file1 (.txt)` in a `.csv` file `(file2)` between two column already exsting.

ex. FILE 1 (.txt)

```
aaaaa   AA
bbbbb   A
ccccc   AB
```

FILE 2   (.csv)

```
vnght   234    ghy
thryu   567    guuu
ghru    456    guuu
```

OUTPUT   (.csv)

```
vnght   234    AA    ghy
thryu   567    A     guuu
ghru    456    AB    guuu
```

How can I do that?

---

[image]

### file 1, i want copy column 2..

[image]

This is the file1 and the column that i want to copy is the second

[image]r.com/XZaxL.png

### This is the file in which i wan copy the column between column 3 and 4

[image]
I don't understand, this is the result.

Answer (score 2):

With `paste` and `cut`

```
paste -d, <(cut -d',' -f 1,2 file2.csv) \
          <(cut -d$'\t' -f2 file1.txt) \
          <(cut -d',' -f 3 file2.csv)
```

Tests

```
$ cat file1.txt
aaaaa   AA
bbbbb   A
ccccc   AB

$ cat file2.csv
vnght,234,ghy
thryu,567,guuu
ghru,456,guuu

$ paste -d, <(cut -d',' -f 1,2 file2.csv) \
            <(cut -d$'\t' -f2 file1.txt) \
            <(cut -d',' -f 3 file2.csv)
vnght,234,AA,ghy
thryu,567,A,guuu
ghru,456,AB,guuu
```

If file2.csv has more additional columns at right and the goal is to maintain that columns the script has to be adjusted to

```
$ paste -d, <(cut -d',' -f1,2 file2.csv) \
            <(cut -d$'\t' -f2 file1.txt) \
            <(cut -d',' -f3- file2.csv)
vnght,234,AA,ghy
thryu,567,A,guuu
ghru,456,AB,guuu
```

Comment: It works but unfortunately only in part because in the output file it doesn't keep the fourth column. inserts the desired one as third but eliminates the fourth

Comment: Can you update the examples in your question with the correct content of your files?

Comment: Is your goal to insert column 2 of file 1 between column 3 and 4 and keep all other columns existing in file 2?

Comment: yes! Exactly...

Comment: @TommasoPalomba See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant, assuming file1 and file2 are in your pwd...

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while read -r line
do
  FIELD2=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
  LINEFROMFILE2=$(sed "${i}q;d" ./file2)
  echo "$LINEFROMFILE2" | awk -v field="$FIELD2" '{$3=$3" "field} {print $0}'
  ((i++))
done < file1
```

Comment: Corrected var order in last awk. I misread 2nd field instead of 3rd. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

With `paste` and `awk`:

```
paste <(awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' file2)\
      <(awk '{print $2}' file1)\
      <(awk '{print $3}' file2)\
      > output
```